# print the sum of the numers occurences in array by using recursive method- java

Tags: java, computer-science

i want to write a recursive method that prints the sum of occurrences in an array without using loops in the method. 
for example if the method get array - arr{1,1,2,3,3,3,3}
the method will print 1:2 2:1 3:4
for this i write a few method
first method that sort the array
seconed method that get array index and the number in this index and return the next index of different number for example to the array above the funcJump(arr,1,1)
will return 3 beacuse thats the first index of different num for 1.
what i think to do to solve this problem is first use the function to sort the array and then to write two punctions
`public static void printFrequencies(int[]arr)//will print 
public  static int printFrequencies(int[]arr,int ix){//scan the array and send`
to the void function the sum of occurences
what i think is to use the function "jump" to get the different indexes and send them to the void function for print but i really stuck to apply this way of thinking to my program.
what do you think thats a good idea?
how can i applay this in my program?

Comment: A good thing is to provide the current code you have written, and also show some of your thinking regarding the approach you want to make with some "Mock code". It is easier to get a full picture, and give you some pointers that way. Instead of providing you a full solution.

Comment: Just to make sure you know: this can be solved without recursion.  If you want to forge ahead with a recursive solution anyway, I won't protest further...

Comment: please see what I've tried https://pastebin.com/WzC8ABJY

Answer (score 0):

```
public void printFrequencies(Integer[] array){
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i<array.length;i++){
        Integer temp = array[i];
        Integer count = map.get(temp);
        if(null == count){
            map.put(temp, 1);
        }else{
            map.put(temp, map.get(temp)+1);
        }
    }
    for(Integer key : map.keySet()){
        System.out.println(key+":"+map.get(key));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I read your code, and I think it's better to understand, and in order to remove duplicate items, I used map.

```
public class Part01 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] nums = {1,2,2,1,1,3,3,4};
    Part01 part01 = new Part01();
    part01.countAllNumber(nums);
}

public int countNumber(int[] nums,int num){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < nums.length;i++){
        if(nums[i] == num)
            count++;
    }

    return count;
}

public void countAllNumber(int[] nums){
    Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    for(int i = 0;i < nums.length;i++){
        int count = countNumber(nums, nums[i]);
        map.put(nums[i], count);
    }

    for(Integer key : map.keySet()){
        System.out.println(key+":"+map.get(key));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: LOOPS AND MAPS ARE NOT ALLOWED TO USE ITS A TASK TO SCHOOL THEY WANT WE USE ONLY IN THE METHODs I WROTE AND RECURSIVE...